# How can I add right side border line to the right side after each main heading of table column

Tags: html, asp.net-core, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to give a border line to right side of each column from   the  main heading  to  end of the  rows. At the moment , the user confuse each input  box and checkbox  related what column even if the position are right. Just want to give a narrow border line after each column heading  and that line would help the user to identify the data  related to what column. the line should be from each heading to end of the corresponding data column Here is the code

```html
!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    text-align: center;
    font: smaller;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  }
  
  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  div.showinline {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>
<html lang="en">

<table id="attendance" class="cell-border dataTable no-footer" style="width: 100%;" role="grid" aria-describedby="attendance_info">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr role="row">
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
      <td style="width:16.66%" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Employee</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle; " rowspan="1" colspan="1">Normal Attendance</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Scheduled DayOff</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Holiday</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="1" colspan="1">ShiftDay</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Other</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Sick</td>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="1">Time off</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Extra Time</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:250px" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Comment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label=": activate to sort column descending" style="width: 1px;"></td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 61px;"></td>

      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 72px;">Time</td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 66px;">Time</td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 47px;">Time</td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 55px;">Time</td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 59px;">Time</td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 39px;">Time</td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 39px;">Time</td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Salary Deduct: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 45px;">Salary Deduct</td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 32px;"></td>
      <td class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="attendance" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 62px;"></td>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>


    <tr style="background-color:#90EE90" role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The LogID field is required." id="attendanceLogList_0__LogID" name="attendanceLogList[0].LogID" value="197211">
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsProtected field is required." id="attendanceLogList_0__IsProtected" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsProtected" value="True">
      </td>
      <td style="width:10%">Employee1</td>



      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsNormalAttendance field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_0__IsNormalAttendance" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsNormalAttendance" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NormalHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The NormalHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_0__NormalHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].NormalHrs" value="3.00">
        </div>
      </td>


      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsDayOffMarked field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_0__IsDayOffMarked" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsDayOffMarked" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DayOffHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The DayOffHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_0__DayOffHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].DayOffHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsHolidayMarked field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_0__IsHolidayMarked" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsHolidayMarked" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HolidayHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The HolidayHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_0__HolidayHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].HolidayHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsFurlough field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_0__IsFurlough" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsFurlough" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FurloughHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The FurloughHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_0__FurloughHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].FurloughHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsMaternityLeave field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_0__IsMaternityLeave" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsMaternityLeave" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MaternityHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The MaternityHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_0__MaternityHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].MaternityHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsSickMarked field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_0__IsSickMarked" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsSickMarked" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SickHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The SickHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_0__SickHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].SickHrs" value="4.30">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsTimeOff field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_0__IsTimeOff" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsTimeOff" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TimeOffHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The TimeOffHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_0__TimeOffHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].TimeOffHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExtraTimeHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The ExtraTimeHrs field is required."
          id="attendanceLogList_0__ExtraTimeHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].ExtraTimeHrs" value="0.00">
      </td>
      <td class="text">
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control" id="attendanceLogList_0__Remark" name="attendanceLogList[0].Remark" value="ssdf">
      </td>


    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#FFBF00" role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The LogID field is required." id="attendanceLogList_1__LogID" name="attendanceLogList[1].LogID" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsProtected field is required." id="attendanceLogList_1__IsProtected" name="attendanceLogList[1].IsProtected" value="False">
      </td>
      <td style="width:10%">Employee2</td>


      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsNormalAttendance field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_1__IsNormalAttendance" name="attendanceLogList[1].IsNormalAttendance" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NormalHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The NormalHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_1__NormalHrs" name="attendanceLogList[1].NormalHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>


      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsDayOffMarked field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_1__IsDayOffMarked" name="attendanceLogList[1].IsDayOffMarked" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DayOffHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The DayOffHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_1__DayOffHrs" name="attendanceLogList[1].DayOffHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsHolidayMarked field is required." id="attendanceLogList_1__IsHolidayMarked"
                            name="attendanceLogList[1].IsHolidayMarked" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HolidayHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The HolidayHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_1__HolidayHrs" name="attendanceLogList[1].HolidayHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsFurlough field is required." id="attendanceLogList_1__IsFurlough"
                            name="attendanceLogList[1].IsFurlough" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FurloughHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The FurloughHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_1__FurloughHrs" name="attendanceLogList[1].FurloughHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsMaternityLeave field is required." id="attendanceLogList_1__IsMaternityLeave"
                            name="attendanceLogList[1].IsMaternityLeave" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MaternityHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The MaternityHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_1__MaternityHrs" name="attendanceLogList[1].MaternityHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsSickMarked field is required." id="attendanceLogList_1__IsSickMarked"
                            name="attendanceLogList[1].IsSickMarked" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SickHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The SickHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_1__SickHrs" name="attendanceLogList[1].SickHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsTimeOff field is required." id="attendanceLogList_1__IsTimeOff"
                            name="attendanceLogList[1].IsTimeOff" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TimeOffHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The TimeOffHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_1__TimeOffHrs" name="attendanceLogList[1].TimeOffHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExtraTimeHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The ExtraTimeHrs field is required."
          id="attendanceLogList_1__ExtraTimeHrs" name="attendanceLogList[1].ExtraTimeHrs" value="0.00">
      </td>
      <td class="text">
        <input type="text" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" class="form-control" id="attendanceLogList_1__Remark" name="attendanceLogList[1].Remark" value="">
      </td>


    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#90EE90" role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The LogID field is required." id="attendanceLogList_2__LogID" name="attendanceLogList[2].LogID" value="197210">
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsProtected field is required." id="attendanceLogList_2__IsProtected" name="attendanceLogList[2].IsProtected" value="True">
      </td>
      <td style="width:10%">Employee3</td>



      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsNormalAttendance field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_2__IsNormalAttendance" name="attendanceLogList[2].IsNormalAttendance" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NormalHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The NormalHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_2__NormalHrs" name="attendanceLogList[2].NormalHrs" value="7.30">
        </div>
      </td>


      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsDayOffMarked field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_2__IsDayOffMarked" name="attendanceLogList[2].IsDayOffMarked" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DayOffHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The DayOffHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_2__DayOffHrs" name="attendanceLogList[2].DayOffHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsHolidayMarked field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_2__IsHolidayMarked" name="attendanceLogList[2].IsHolidayMarked" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HolidayHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The HolidayHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_2__HolidayHrs" name="attendanceLogList[2].HolidayHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsFurlough field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_2__IsFurlough" name="attendanceLogList[2].IsFurlough" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FurloughHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The FurloughHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_2__FurloughHrs" name="attendanceLogList[2].FurloughHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsMaternityLeave field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_2__IsMaternityLeave" name="attendanceLogList[2].IsMaternityLeave" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MaternityHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The MaternityHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_2__MaternityHrs" name="attendanceLogList[2].MaternityHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsSickMarked field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_2__IsSickMarked" name="attendanceLogList[2].IsSickMarked" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SickHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The SickHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_2__SickHrs" name="attendanceLogList[2].SickHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="showinline">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsTimeOff field is required."
                            id="attendanceLogList_2__IsTimeOff" name="attendanceLogList[2].IsTimeOff" value="true">
                    </span>
          <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TimeOffHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The TimeOffHrs field is required."
            id="attendanceLogList_2__TimeOffHrs" name="attendanceLogList[2].TimeOffHrs" value="0.00">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control format-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExtraTimeHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The ExtraTimeHrs field is required."
          id="attendanceLogList_2__ExtraTimeHrs" name="attendanceLogList[2].ExtraTimeHrs" value="0.00">
      </td>
      <td class="text">
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90" class="form-control" id="attendanceLogList_2__Remark" name="attendanceLogList[2].Remark" value="">
      </td>


    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you want to distinguish them easily, in general, you can do the following.

1. Bold border.
2. Change the color of the column.
3. Increase the space between columns.

Example:

```
table {
border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
  th,
  td {
  text-align: center;
  font: smaller;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 25%; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/to4jwu72/3/